# Whats the best way of accessing django database with python script?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a django project which is made for running a website.

I want to have a python script that is going to read django database and insert new data.

Whats the best way of doing that? I assume that if I would just regulary connect to the database (using sqlite library for example) it might cause some conflicts because django app and my script are accessing same database at the same time.

Comment: Django already has infrastructure to connect to the database. Exactly *what* do you want to do? Can you give an example what you aim to achieve.

Comment: But using the sqlite database yourself would likely result in a lot of problems: the main problem with sqlite: it can not handle multiple modifications or modifications and reads at the same time. Exactly for that reason Django uses a pool to prevent getting the file in a corrupt state.

Answer (score 2):

> I want to have a python script that is going to read django database and insert new data.

IMHO, this does not sound like a very good idea because accessing and modifying an application's database outside of it opens up possibilities to mistakes and to corrupt the data, for example, too easily.

> Whats the best way of doing that?

In your Django application, I would create an API that you could call from your scripts to both read from and write data to the database. This would make sure that all your input data is validated according to your Django models, and access to the data is handled according to your access policies, if any.

For a Django application, I think using the [Django REST framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) might be easiest way to accomplish what you want.

Finally, you could use Python scripts or any other HTTP tool to make requests to your application's API.